# Creating pseudo anchors in TikZ drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a complex TikZ sub-drawing (I call it “object”) that I use over and over in many figures. It's way more complex than what's called a “shape” in the TikZ/pgf context and contains itself several nodes. It has some connection points like the anchors of a shape, and I define them with `coordinate (object name_connection name)`. If it would be real anchors of a shape, I could use the syntax `(object name.connection name)`, but that's not possible in standard tikz (also stated in the manual). Is there a way to circumvent this and give a name containing a “.” to a coordinate? It would help to have cleaner code and to stay closer to the TikZ/pgf syntax.

The example below illustrates what I mean. It's kind of **minimal** working example, my original code is at the moment approx. 200 lines of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
  /object/.cd,
  left node/.style={draw,red},
  right node/.style={draw,blue},
}

\def\object[#1](#2,#3)#4;{
  \pgfkeys{/object/.cd,#1}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2,#3)}]
    \node [/object/left node] (#4_left) at (-1,0) {#4};
    \node [/object/right node]  (#4_right) at (1,0) {#4};
    \draw (#4_left) -- (#4_right);
    \draw (#4_right) -- ++(.5,.5) coordinate (#4_connection b);
    \draw (#4_left) -- ++(-.5,-.5) coordinate (#4_connection a);
  \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \object[](0,-1){A};
  \object[left node/.append style={green}](0,1){B};
  \begin{scope}[orange]
    \draw (-2,0) -- (A_connection a);
    % \draw (-2,0) -- (A.connection a);
    \draw (A_connection b) to[out=45,in=225] (B_connection a);
    % \draw (A.connection b) to[out=45,in=225] (B.connection a);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Related: [Complex objects in TikZ: pgfkeys scope and best practice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95340/complex-objects-in-tikz-pgfkeys-scope-and-best-practice)

Comment: You could declare your object as shape with `\pgfdeclareshape`, and then provide code for as many anchors as you wish

Comment: @Lionel MANSUY: Yes, but that's what I try to avoid, because I don't want to use basic pgf to define my object but higher level TikZ structures like shown in the example.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid pgf?

Comment: I have several reasons. 1) I have already >230 lines of TikZ code. 2) I utilize styles and node positioning a lot within my object and it utilizes additionally several circuit elements. 3) I have many years of TikZ experience, using it during studies, diploma thesis and many papers. I used `\def` to define my objects since I was never able to dig into the complexity of pgf. So I have 0 years of pgf experience. I'm not a programmer, and pgf looks really complex. I had always the impression that TikZ is lacking some higher level object facility. I believe a lot of people use C-c C-v instead.

Comment: What about declaring generic anchors with `\pgfdeclaregenericanchor`? It's undocumented, it seems... :-(  but I've used it already so I know it works.  ---But that's pgf again, I'm afraid ...

Comment: @SašoŽivanović: I tried to understand how that command works and how it can be utilized. Since there's no documentation, I tried the google approach. If I understand it correct, it can also be utilized only within a `\pgfdeclareshape` structure. For the future, I'll try to understand how that works, if I can use nodes and other TikZ level code within `\pgfdeclareshape` and how I can utilize pgfkeys within `\pgfdeclareshape`. But for my already defined objects I still search for a solution.

Comment: I will post the code below, but first a disclaimer: taking a closer look at your problem, I now think that the `\pgfdeclaregenericanchor` would be too much work for too little gain (namely nicer syntax).  (I have primarily used `\pgfdeclaregenericanchor` to be able to access saved anchors and macros of shapes shipped with `tikz`. That was the only way I could think of to do that.)

Answer (score 4):

As you can see, the primary goal is met: it's possible to write `(A.connection left)`.

However: the information about coordinates within the object is duplicated, and when more than one object type comes into play, we need to distinguish between them. So, to make everything really work, one would need to the store object type and some internal coordinates ... which would essentially duplicate pgf's shape mechanism.

Another thing: an anchor (including generic anchors) returns a point, so `(A.left)` doesn't really refer to the node, but to its anchor. In other words, I don't believe that recursion `(A.left.north)` can be implemented in this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
  /object/.cd,
  left node/.style={draw,red},
  right node/.style={draw,blue},
}

\def\object[#1](#2,#3)#4;{
  \pgfkeys{/object/.cd,#1}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2,#3)}]
    \path coordinate(#4);
    \node [/object/left node] (#4_left) at (-1,0) {#4};
    \node [/object/right node]  (#4_right) at (1,0) {#4};
    \draw (#4_left) -- (#4_right);
    \draw (#4_left) -- ++(-.5,-.5);
    \draw (#4_right) -- ++(.5,.5);
  \end{scope}
}
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{left}{\pgfpointxy{-1}{0}}
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{right}{\pgfpointxy{1}{0}}
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{connection left}{\pgfpointxy{-1.5}{-0.5}}
\pgfdeclaregenericanchor{connection right}{\pgfpointxy{1.5}{0.5}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \object[](0,-1){A};
  \object[left node/.append style={green}](0,1){B};
  \begin{scope}[orange]
    \draw[->] (-2,0) -- (A.connection left);
    \draw (A.connection right) to[out=45,in=225] (B.connection left);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```