# Renaming anchors in predefined shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

I am drawing several dozen diagrams with TikZ that will be using equilateral triangles.  My current setup is using the regular polygon construction.  The anchor names corner 1, corner 2, and corner 3 are not very semantic for my purposes, so I would like to make a global declaration providing them new names.  This is how I am currently declaring my triangular nodes:

```
\tikzset{
delta/.style={
regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum size=0.4cm, inner sep=0,
outer sep=0.025em, draw=black, very thick, fill=green!10}
}
```

I know that `(node.210)` will give me the same anchor position as `(node.corner 2)`, but I'd like to be able to do something like `(node.left copy)` to give the same anchor position, and `(node.right copy)` in the place of `(node.corner 3)` or `(node.330)`.
From the manual, it seems I ought to be able to do something like `\anchor{left copy}{\corner2}` if \corner2 is the name for that saved anchor, but I don't know where that code would fit into what I have, and I don't know if \corner2 is the correct name.
The following code is functional, but customizing the anchor names will make it easier to follow what's going on in a more complicated diagram.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[-, thick]
\node[delta] (dub) {};
\node (copy1) [below left of=dub] {};
\node (copy2) [below right of=dub] {};
\node (input) [above of=dub] {};
\draw (input) -- (dub) (dub.corner 2) -- (copy1);
\draw (dub.corner 3) -- (copy2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The best workaround I have found so far is rotating the border in the style definition, `shape border rotate=120`, which lowers each of the used corner numbers by 1.  Even if I end up using this hack here, rotation is not a panacea; I still want to know how to make new aliases for anchors in predefined shapes.

A comment on another question ([Creating pseudo anchors in TikZ drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95700/creating-pseudo-anchors-in-tikz-drawing?rq=1)) indicated `\pgfdeclaregenericanchor` is an undocumented macro that can be used to access saved anchors of predefined shapes, but that's where I hit a dead end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\pgfdeclareanchoralias{<shape>}{<anchor>}{<alias>}` defined as

```
\newcommand*\pgfdeclareanchoralias[3]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@anchor@#1@#3\expandafter\endcsname
            \expandafter{\csname pgf@anchor@#1@#2\endcsname}}
```

can be used to copy the definition of the `<anchor>` anchor of the `<shape>` shape under the new name `<alias>`, so in your case

```
\pgfdeclareanchoralias{regular polygon}{corner 2}{left copy}
\pgfdeclareanchoralias{regular polygon}{corner 3}{right copy}
```

should do.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}
\newcommand*\pgfdeclareanchoralias[3]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgf@anchor@#1@#3\expandafter\endcsname
            \expandafter{\csname pgf@anchor@#1@#2\endcsname}}

\pgfdeclareanchoralias{regular polygon}{corner 2}{left copy}
\pgfdeclareanchoralias{regular polygon}{corner 3}{right copy}
\tikzset{
  delta/.style={
    regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, minimum size=0.4cm, inner sep=0,
    outer sep=0.025em, draw=black, very thick, fill=green!10}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, node distance=.25cm]
\node[delta] (dub) {};
\coordinate [ below left=of dub.left copy]  (copy1);
\coordinate [below right=of dub.right copy] (copy2);
\coordinate [      above=of dub]            (input);
\path (input)          edge (dub)
      (dub.left copy)  edge (copy1)
      (dub.right copy) edge (copy2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried putting both code blocks in my preamble immediately after `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}`.  I also tried adding it in after the style declaration.  That part compiled, but in both cases `(dub.left copy)` threw an error:  Unknown function `left' (in 'left copy').  There was a similar error for right copy.

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I just checked, the `corner <i>` anchors are created on-the-fly when they are needed (so in your case when the `delta` node is created). I’ll change the solution to a more robust version.

Comment: In retrospect, it makes sense that the corners are not saved anchors.  This alias maker for anchors, as modified, is just what the doctor ordered.