# Simple example of pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value

I'm struggling to get my head around the [`pgfkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) package. I currently use the [`keycommand`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keycommand) package, which I find very easy to understand: it's just ordinary LaTeX commands with named rather than numbered arguments. However, I would like to use `pgfkeys` because my project is heavily based on TikZ, and I believe it is a more powerful solution. I think understanding how to translate the following little example from `keycommand` to `pgfkeys` would help me a lot.

### Example

I make a command to draw a `doublecircle` gadget. It has two arguments: `diameter` and `color`, both optional, with default values `1` and `red` respectively.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{keycommand}

\newcounter{currentheight}
\setcounter{currentheight}{0}

\newkeycommand{\doublecircle}[diameter=1,color=red]{%
  \fill[\commandkey{color}] (0,\thecurrentheight) circle (\commandkey{diameter}/2);
  \fill[\commandkey{color}] (\commandkey{diameter}/2,\thecurrentheight) circle (\commandkey{diameter}/2);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
\doublecircle[color=blue]
\addtocounter{currentheight}{5}
\doublecircle[diameter=4]
\addtocounter{currentheight}{6}
\doublecircle[diameter=3,color=green]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: three doublecircle gadgets]

Comment: If you work it out, you become a PGF Master.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you used a counter (only integers) instead of a simple macro or a "value"? Does the `pgfkeys` implementation needs an equivalent `add to height` key?

Comment: No good reason. It's just that I know how to add values to counters, and I don't know how to do that off the top of my head if I had just used a simple macro like `\newcommand{\currentheight}{0}`.

Comment: Have you seen [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values/34318#34318) to a similar question?  It's very popular and seems like exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,% to set the path
  circle height/.initial=0, % initial value
  circle height/.get=\circleheight, % to get the value from a macro
  circle height/.store in=\circleheight, % to store the value into a macro
  diameter/.initial=1,
  diameter/.get=\diameter,
  diameter/.store in=\diameter,
  circle color/.initial=red,
  circle color/.get=\circlecolor,
  circle color/.store in=\circlecolor,
}

\newcommand{\pgfdoublecircle}[1][]{%
  \tikzset{circle color=red,diameter=1,#1}% the default options will be overwritten by the one introduced
  \fill[\circlecolor] (0,\circleheight) circle (\diameter/2);
  \fill[\circlecolor] (\diameter/2,\circleheight) circle (\diameter/2);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
\pgfdoublecircle[circle color=blue]
\pgfdoublecircle[circle height=5,diameter=4]
\pgfdoublecircle[circle height=11,diameter=3,circle color=green]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

According to [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys/114017#comment251607_114017) and other Q/A like [What do the pgfkeys key handlers .get and .store in do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129577/what-do-the-pgfkeys-key-handlers-get-and-store-in-do) and [Arguments for TikZ style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131293/arguments-for-tikz-style) I was convinced to abandon the inefficient method to set up keys. Hence, it should be preferred:

```
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,% to set the path
  circle height/.store in=\circleheight, % to store the value into a macro
  circle height=0, % initial value
  diameter/.store in=\diameter,
  diameter=1,
  circle color/.store in=\circlecolor,
  circle color=red,
}
```

The final result remains obviously consistent with the latter approach.

Comment: I preferred to put clearly the height coordinate rather than with an increasing counter, but that approach is also doable.

Comment: This is splendid, thank you. So much more helpful than poring over the manual!

Comment: I notice that you set `red` as the default `color` twice in the code: you have both `circle color/.initial=red` and `\tikzset{circle color=red,...}`. Is this necessary?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Yes, because the `\pgfdoublecircle` macro isn’t scoped or grouped. The `circle color=blue` will survive the macro expansion and the value will be still `blue` for the next `\pgfdoublecircle`s.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel. In which case, can one manage without setting the `.initial` values?

Comment: @JohnWickerson I don’t know why Claudio uses `.initial` and `.get`. I’d use `circle height/.store in=\circleheight, circle height=0` here.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to get, set and store values, see also the first part of [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95355/16595).
Depending on the key and how its value is needed one must use the one or the other way.

Oftentimes we can also see

```
/my namespace/key/.code=\pgfmathsetmacro\namespace@key{#1}
```

which can be used here too and makes the value available in an already calculated form, though here it isn’t really needed as TikZ throws almost anything in PGF Math itself. See [(yet) another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112474/16595) on how to use this more effectively (the part about the `+`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\newcommand*{\doublecircleset}{\pgfqkeys{/double circle}}
\makeatletter
\doublecircleset{
  /double circle/.code={\pgfqkeys{/double circle}{#1}},
  color/.initial=red, % initialize key 'color' with value 'red'
  height/.initial=0, % see color
  diameter/.store in=\doublecircle@diameter, % the key 'diameter' will be used more than once and also in the 'scope', let's store it right away
  diameter=1,                                % the default value is '1'
  add to height/.style={height/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/double circle/height}+#1} % let's take the value of the 'height' key and add '#1'.
                                                     % expansion is needed otherwise we have a selv-referencing macro (and an infinite loop)
}
\newcommand{\doublecircle}[1][]{%
  % let's group the whole macro so that the changes to the keys and whatnot are local, this is how TikZ works.
  % we could have used '\begingroup \doublecircleset{#1} … … … \endgroup' here, but the scope allows us to set the radius too.
  \scope[/double circle={#1}, radius=(\doublecircle@diameter)/2] % alright, execute the key=values and set the radius
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/double circle/height}\doublecircle@height  % we need the height more than once, a single macro would be nice to use
    \fill[color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/double circle/color}]           %
      (0,{\doublecircle@height}) circle []                       % if we use () or , in the key (which is allowed: PGF math) we need to enclose it in braces
      (xyz cs: x={(\doublecircle@diameter)/2},                   % either way
               y={\doublecircle@height}) circle []
      ;
  \endscope
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm]
\doublecircle[color=blue]
\doublecircleset{add to height=5}
\doublecircle[diameter=4]
\doublecircleset{add to height=6}
\doublecircle[diameter=3, height=2*(2+3), color=green]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Qrrbrbirlbel, I appreciate all the explanations. Is `\scope[X] ... \endscope` the same as `\begin{scope}[X]...\end{scope}`?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Yes, it is (more or less). TikZ includes `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in its environments on its own; using LaTeX’s `\begin` and `\end` would just add another group (and some testing).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Also, what does `xyz cs` mean?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Check the PGF manual for the `xyz` coordinate system. It is simply the explicit version of `(x, y, z)` (where all are initially `0`).