# Bad interaction between keycommand and environ?

Tags: packages, environments, debugging, key-value

I suspect the [`keycommand`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keycommand) and [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) packages are not playing nicely together, because the following code gives an error. Can anybody explain what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Turn scalebox into an environment
\NewEnviron{scaleboxenv}[1]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{\BODY}%
}

% An environment with a named argument
\newkeyenvironment{scaled}[scale=1]{%
  % My real code does some more stuff here
  \begin{scaleboxenv}{\commandkey{scale}}
}{%
  \end{scaleboxenv}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{scaled}[scale=0.7]
Hello
\end{scaled}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `keycommand`; when LaTeX finds `\begin{scaleboxenv}` it need to *see* `\end{scaleboxenv}`, but it doesn't because it finds `\end{scaled}`, which triggers the error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{keycommand}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Turn scalebox into an environment
\NewEnviron{scaleboxenv}[1]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{\BODY}%
}

% An environment with a named argument
\newkeyenvironment{scaled}[scale=1]{%
  % My real code does some more stuff here
  \scaleboxenv{\commandkey{scale}}
}{%
  \endscaleboxenv
}

\begin{document}

\begin{scaled}[scale=0.7]
Hello
\end{scaled}

\end{document}
```

Are you sure you want to use `keycommand`?

Here's a `keycommand` and `environ` free version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{keyval} % already loaded by graphicx

\makeatletter
\newsavebox{\wickscalebox}
\newenvironment{scaled}[1][]
 {%
  % My real code does some more stuff here
  \setkeys{wickscale}{#1}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\wickscalebox}%
 }
 {%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \scalebox{\wick@scale}{\usebox{\wickscalebox}}%
 }
\define@key{wickscale}{scale}{\def\wick@scale{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{scaled}[scale=0.7]
Hello
\end{scaled}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I'm not sure I want to use keycommand, in fact I'm [trying to move to pgfkeys](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys) as we speak.

Comment: Your fix is rather interesting. Is it the case that for any environment `foo` I can replace `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}` with `\foo ... \endfoo`?

Comment: @JohnWickerson No. For example you must never replace `\begin{lrbox}` with `\lrbox`.