# What do the pgfkeys key handlers .get and .store in do?

Tags: pgfkeys

When I need to retrieve the value of a key in a macro, I use the key handlers `.get` and `.store in`. Here is what is written in the *pgfkeys* documentation:

> Key handler key `/.get= macro`
>   Executes a `\let` command so that macro contains the contents stored in key .

> Key handler key `/.store in= macro`
>   This handler has the following effect: When you write `key = value` , the code `\def macro { value }` is
>   executed. Thus, the given value is “stored” in the macro .

I don't really understand the differences between these two handlers. Actually, I would expect `.store in` to be sufficient, and yet I need both. Why?

### Code

Below is typically what I write (without understanding it...) when I use `pgfkeys`:

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{
\pgfkeys{
  /a/.initial=1,
  /a/.get=\aKey,
  /a/.store in=\aKey,
}
\pgfkeys{#1}
a is \aKey
}

\begin{document}
\DisplayKey{a=7}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I use it generally to draw a figure with tikz. This is just a useless minimal example to illustrate my understanding of _pgfkeys_ use. Maybe it will help someone get started. `.initial` is useless here but my point is that I need to use `.get` and `.store in` together if I want to be able to store the value.

Comment: More confusion about `.get` and `.initial`: [Complex objects in TikZ: pgfkeys scope and best practice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95340)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Three answers in and much more confusion (at least on my side).

---

The handlers `.get` and `.store in` are very different and nothing alike.

The `<key>/.store in=\<macro>` handler *sets up* a key `<key>` so that if it is used with `<key>=<value>` it stores `<value>` in `\<macro>`. This is the same as if you would have written `<key>/.code=\def\<macro>{#1}`.

Every time you use the `<key>` the macro `\<macro>` will be (re) defined.

The `.get` handler actually kind of performs the opposite, it takes the current value of the key and stores it in a macro. An un-`.initial`ized key will give you `\relax`.

The `.get` handler is only one of many ways to receive the value of a key in an easily usable macro. (Remember that the key itself is only a macro as well.) Other ways include `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/full/path to/key}\<macro>` or if you don’t need macro `\pgfkeysvalueof{/full/path to/key}`.

---

What you do with

```
\pgfkeys{
  /a/.initial=1,
  /a/.get=\aKey,
  /a/.store in=\aKey,
}
```

is bad practice because you first set up the key to be a “value key” and initialize it with the value `1`. Then you get that `1` and save it in `\aKey` (that’s actually a `\let` but that is not important). Then you change the setup of the key to be a `.store in` key, a key that saves its value in a macro. That has nothing to do with the previous `.initial` key.

This is equivalent to

```
\def\aValue{1}
\let\aKey\aValue
\def\aCommand#1{\def\aKey{#1}}
```

One can see that `\aValue` serves no real purpose. And you actually have used three macros:

- `\aValue` (`\pgfk@/a`),
- `\aKey` and
- `\aCommand` (`\pgfk@/a/.@cmd`).

The same can be achieved with

```
\def\aCommand#1{\def\aKey{#1}}
\aCommand{1}
```

or

```
\def\aCommand#1{\def\aKey{#1}}
\def\aKey{1}
```

or in PGFkeys:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /a/.store in=\aKey,
  /a=1 % this initializes \aKey
}
```

---

As discussed before in [When to use a regular .initial key or a .store in key?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125197/16595), I consider `.store in` obsolete as you need two macros for every key:

- one for the key itself that performs the `\def` and
- one that stores the actual value.

This is very similar to the basic macros `\title` which is defined as

```
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}
% or
\newcommand*{\title}[1]{\def\@title{#1}}
```

But (La)TeX doesn’t have the possibility to say `\title{<something>}` and if you use `\title` without an argument it gives you `<something>`.

But this basically is the nature of an `.initial` key.

#### References

- Q: [When to use a regular .initial key or a .store in key?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125197/16595)
- C: [Simple example of pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys/114017#comment251607_114017)
- A: [A way to setup a pure value key without defining an initial vaue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125081/16595)

Comment: That's not quite correct actually. See Claudio's answer. You need `.get` to extract the value from `.initial`. See the explanation in the manual for `.get` with `red` and `blue`. But I don't like the construction anyway. Probably it's a CS thingy that I don't understand.

Comment: @percusse What specifically is “not quite correct”? I don’t say that you don’t need `.get`.

Comment: The part with *kind of wrong*. That's strangely the recommended way by the TikZ team. And we have expansion control issues etc. So it's not that straightforward

Comment: @percusse That “kind of wrong” describes the whole sequence of `.initial`, `.get` and `.store in`. The `.get` handler itself is useful (in a context that does not need to be expandable).

Comment: Again, with `.initial` key you can't use the initial value. The manual has a blue and red example that shows what the key is promoted to. so you need to squeeze in `.get` there to initialize the macro used in `/.store in`. Otherwise you hit the error what Claudio shown with undefined macro. I've commented to him also about your suggestion but still it's not optimal.

Comment: @percusse And here I was thinking I am reducing the confusion. — Bottom line of my answer: Do not use `.initial` and `.store in` on the same key. Either use `.store in` (or don’t, see the reference) or use `.initial` and “get” the value when you need it in one of many ways (`.get`, `\pgfkeysgetvalue` or `\pgfkeysvalueof`).

Comment: It is indeed very strange. Probably we need a PhD in CS to make sense out of it.

Answer (score 10):

You can check the mechanism with the example below. `get` assigns the current value of the key to a macro and we are done. `store in` is instead keeps whatever argument is passed to the key itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{a/.initial=1}
\pgfkeys{a/.get=\aKey}%

\aKey        %1
\pgfkeys{a=7}%
\aKey        %2
\pgfkeys{a}  %3
\aKey        %4
\pgfkeys{a/.get=\aKey}%
\aKey        %5

\par
\aKey        % Still 7
\pgfkeys{a/.store in=\aKey}
\pgfkeys{a=1}%
\aKey        % Now 1 Without 'get'ting

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your example you are getting the value of the key `a` to `\aKey` but then overwriting it with `store in`. If you remove the `get` part it will keep on working.

Comment: Indeed, removing the `.get` part works... And yet, I was pretty sure I had tried it before without success... strange!

Comment: @remjg It's not strange but a little abused. The initial value is not directly available for use and that's what Claudio is explaining.

Comment: Could you explain to me why `\pgfkeys{a}` displays something? Also, why does it display 7?

Comment: I've read in an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125224/19042) to the question [When to use a regular .initial key or a .store in key?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125197/when-to-use-a-regular-initial-key-or-a-store-in-key) that `pgfkeys{a}` displays the content of the key if there is no handler `.default` to the key. I understand your example now!

Comment: @remjg In the evening, I'll take another look. As Qrr mentioned, this is far from a satisfactory answer and needs some under the hood demo. Where is Ryan Reich when you need him?

Answer (score 4):

Well the manual is actually pretty clear in the wording, your question is then targeted about the difference of `\let` and `\def`.

For a difference between `\let` and `\def` please see: [What is the difference between \let and \def?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def)

Might I also point to the attention of:

> Key handler `<key>/.estore in=<macro>`

instead of `\def` as in `.store in` it executes an `\edef`.
For further reference on this topic see:
[What is the difference between \let and \edef?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-edef)

#### The problem

You should not mix the usage of `.store in` and `.get` as they do *the same thing differently*.

The key `.store in` enables you to overcome the need for getting keys from `pgfkeys` by the use of a single macro.

By doing `\pgfkeys{/a/.store in=\aKey}` you will then always have `\aKey` be the value that is assigned. Note that `\aKey` is not a macro until `a=<value>` gets executed.

Take this example:

```
\newcommand{\showa}{a is \aKey}

% Try and switch between these two
\pgfkeys{a/.store in=\aKey}
%\pgfkeys{a/.get=\aKey}

\pgfkeys{a=1}
\showa
\pgfkeys{a=2}
\showa
\pgfkeys{a=3}
\showa
```

This will print:

> a is 1 a is 2 a is 3

The first `pgfkeys` is simply to reference the value of a to `\aKey`. In effect each time `a=<something>` is done you actually do `\def{\aKey}{<something>}`.
Hence this should *only* be performed once.

The `.get` will behave differently but can be used to achieve the same effect. However, certain cases where you need to control the expansion of `\aKey` will let you choose whichever case you prefer.

#### Your code

Your code should then be something like this:

```
\pgfkeys{a/.store in=\aKey}
\pgfkeys{a/.initial=1}
\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{
    \pgfkeys{#1}
    a is \aKey
}
\DisplayKey{a=7}
\DisplayKey{a=3}
```

and it will print `a is 7 a is 3`.

Comment: No worries, I'm currently reading the `\let`, `\def`, `\edef` explanations you gave me as a link... I still have many things to learn!

Comment: You said that _The .get will behave almost the same (in the above example the same)_. Actually, since the `\let` instruction (induced by the `.get` handler) is done before the key `a` is defined, the resulting macro `\aKey` is empty. Here is the output I get: `a is  a is  a is`

Comment: @remjg I don't know why i wrote that, I am sorry. I will delete it from my test example! Sorry for my late response!

Comment: no worries, I've learned a lot thanks to you anyway!

Answer (score 4):

I also use this approach even if it is not the only possible with `pgfkeys`, see [Qrrbrbirbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) comment in [Simple example of pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys/114017#comment251607_114017).

I would like to add a common-sense explanation to [zeroth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7049/zeroth) answer.

Assuming *x* be the initial value of the key `key-x`, thanks to the handler `store in` it is passed to the macro, say `\macro@x`. Usually, you want to use this macro somewhere and very likely you don't want to be forced to pass values to it every time. This because can be possible that the `key-x` uses *x* most of the times and it should change its value only few times. Now you can use `\macro@x` in your application being sure at the beginning it has *x* as initial value.

Suppose now to call your application passing to `key-x` another value, say `y`. One might think: now `\macro@x` should contain `y`. Well, that's not true. It becomes true only if you added the handler `get` to `key-x`, otherwise you will end up with errors.

As demonstration, look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  N/.initial=10,
  N/.get=\N,
  N/.store in=\N,
}


\newcommand{\showN}[1][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\m{\N/5}
\node{\m};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\showN
\showN[N=20]
\showN


\end{document}
```

This prints:

> 2 4 2

when the `get` handler is present, otherwise:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \N
/5
l.21 \showN
[N=20]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Just for reference, one may avoid completely the `initial` and `get` handlers with the following approach:

```
\def\N{10}%
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,%
  N/.store in=\N,%
}%
```

By substituting this in the previous MWE, it is correctly printed:

> 2 4 2

As a matter of facts, you have seen there are several ways to achieve the same result: just the programming styles are different.

Comment: The problem is that the key is not set when you call it initially. Instead of using `get`, you can use `default`. But you need to call the key to make the initial assignment.

Comment: Scratch that. I think I don't like the construction and complaining for no reason. Never mind my comment.

Comment: @percusse: haha, no problems at all. :)

Comment: Of course, without `.get` the `\N` macro is undefined because you do not initialize it even though you use `.initial` (which initialize a “value key” and nothing more). I may repeat myself, but don’t use `.initial` if you want to do `.store in`. Simply do `N/.store in=\N, N=<initial value>` (or the quicker `\def\N{<initial value>`). Even more so, there is still a “value key” present which you can access with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/N}` but it is in no relation to `\N` and cannot be set with `N=<value>`. You have defined now three macros: `\pgfk@/tikz/N`, `\pgfk@/tikz/N/.@cmd` and `\N`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: as I said in the last part of my answer, I believe this is more a matter of programming style. It's true that the "triple" procedure is not optimum, but one "should"/"would" care only if it he's developing a huge package. Then, this may lead to endless discussion as I prefer call `\N` rather than `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/N}` for future code readability. But, you know, there lots of things to be traded (commodity in writing code, purpose of the code).

Comment: BTW: Once I also faced a problem with `store in` "only" approach about the key-value consistency while performing different operations (was something related to an early version of mine sa-tikz), and that was the primary cause which made me start using the handler triple.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not going to give an answer to my question, but just practical examples to observe the behaviour of the key handlers `.get` and `.store in`. Your answers helped me a lot but I needed a good night of sleep to set things in order and these examples to be able to try different configurations.

Since setting an initial value (handler `.initial`) and a default value (handler `.default`) is often a related problem, I also want to write here some details I've gathered:

- if there is a default value: `pgfkeys{a}` will set the default value to the key `a`
- if there is no default value: `pgfkeys{a}` displays the value of the key `a`

### Examples with the `.get` handler

I have used a default value in the examples of this section to avoid displaying twice the key `a` when calling `\DisplayKey{a}`.

Each time, I've generated two outputs: the one on the right corresponds to the case where an *initial value* of 0 is used for the key `a`.

#### Example 1

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/a/.default=1}
\pgfkeys{/a/.initial=0} % uncomment for image on the right    

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/a/.get=\aKey}% .get before setting key a
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  \aKey}%

\begin{document}
  a / value stored in \textbackslash aKey\par
  ? / \DisplayKey{}\par
  1 / \DisplayKey{a}\par
  2 / \DisplayKey{a=2}\par
  3 / \DisplayKey{a=3}\par
  4 / \DisplayKey{a=4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: .get before setting the key] [image: .get before setting the key with initial value]

#### Example 2

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/a/.default=1}
\pgfkeys{/a/.initial=0} % uncomment for image on the right

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  \pgfkeys{/a/.get=\aKey}% .get after setting key a
  \aKey}%

\begin{document}
  a / value stored in \textbackslash aKey\par
  ? / \DisplayKey{}\par
  1 / \DisplayKey{a}\par
  2 / \DisplayKey{a=2}\par
  3 / \DisplayKey{a=3}\par
  4 / \DisplayKey{a=4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: .get after setting the key] [image: .get after setting the key with initial value]

#### Example 3

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{/a/.default=1}
\pgfkeys{/a/.initial=0} % uncomment for image on the right
\pgfkeys{/a/.get=\aKey}% .get before every setting operation to the key

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  \aKey}%

\begin{document}
  a / value stored in \textbackslash aKey\par
  ? / \DisplayKey{}\par
  1 / \DisplayKey{a}\par
  2 / \DisplayKey{a=2}\par
  3 / \DisplayKey{a=3}\par
  4 / \DisplayKey{a=4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: .get at the beginning before any setting operation to the key] [image: .get at the beginning before any setting operation to the key with initial value]

### Examples with the `.store in` handler

I have used an initial value of 0 in every examples of this section. Indeed, the macro `\aKey` doesn't exist until `a` is set for the first time (`\DisplayKey{}` doesn't set `a` but asks for `\aKey` so it needs to be defined before).

Each time, I've generated two outputs: the one on the right corresponds to the case where an *default value* of 1 is used for the key `a`.

#### Example 4

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /a/.default=1, % uncomment to get image on the right
  /a/.store in=\aKey, % .store in at the beginning before any setting operation to the key
  a=0} % set a, calls .store in and defines \aKey (otherwise \DisplayKey{} would produce an error)

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  \aKey}%

\begin{document}
  a / value stored in \textbackslash aKey\par
  ? / \DisplayKey{}\par
  1 / \DisplayKey{a}\par
  2 / \DisplayKey{a=2}\par
  3 / \DisplayKey{a=3}\par
  4 / \DisplayKey{a=4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: .store in at the beginning before any setting operation to the key] [image: .store in at the beginning before any setting operation to the key with default value]

#### Example 5 (bad)

And here is what I was doing...

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /a/.default=1, % uncomment to get image on the right
  /a/.initial=0,
  /a/.get=\aKey, % if you remove it, \DisplayKey{} generates an error (\aKey not defined)
  /a/.store in=\aKey} % \aKey will be redefined each time a is set

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  \aKey}%

\begin{document}
  a / value stored in \textbackslash aKey\par
  ? / \DisplayKey{}\par
  1 / \DisplayKey{a}\par
  2 / \DisplayKey{a=2}\par
  3 / \DisplayKey{a=3}\par
  4 / \DisplayKey{a=4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: a bad way of doing things] [image: a bad way of doing things with default value 1]

### Bonus

I also want to mention another solution which makes use of the handler `.code` and the macros `\pgfkeyssetvalue` and `\pgfkeysgetvalue`. Indeed, it makes things easy to [test weather a key has been set](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129567/19042).

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /a/.default=1, % uncomment to get image on the right
  /a/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{a}{#1}\pgfkeysgetvalue{a}{\aKey}},
  a=0}

\newcommand{\DisplayKey}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{#1}%
  \aKey}%

\begin{document}
  a / value stored in \textbackslash aKey\par
  ? / \DisplayKey{}\par
  1 / \DisplayKey{a}\par
  2 / \DisplayKey{a=2}\par
  3 / \DisplayKey{a=3}\par
  4 / \DisplayKey{a=4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: Using \pgfkeyssetvalue and \pgfkeysgetvalue] [image: Using \pgfkeyssetvalue and \pgfkeysgetvalue with a defaut value]