# Can keyval and pgfkeys produce identical results?

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value

I've spent about five hours (!) studying [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/218142) (and other resources) and trying to understand how to implement key values and it's been extremely confusing. I have written an essentially trivial (for most people here, anyway) test case and there are some inconsistencies I can't explain.

Here is an MWE using `keyval`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
% Key definitions
\define@key{sayhello}{towhom}{\def\sh@towhom{#1}}
% Key defaults
\setkeys{sayhello}{towhom=Michael}
% Define the command that uses the key
\newcommand{\sayhello}[2][]{%
  %\begingroup% localizes the new settings w/o calling the defaults
  \setkeys{sayhello}{towhom=Michael} % Reset defaults w/o localizing
  \setkeys{sayhello}{#1} % Set new keys
  Say hello to \sh@towhom\ #2.
  %\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\sayhello{tomorrow}

%\sayhello[towhom]{today} % throws no value specified for towhom

\sayhello[towhom=Jill]{tomorrow}

%\sayhello[towhom]{today} % throws no value specified for towhom

\sayhello[towhom=Joe]{tomorrow}

%\sayhello[towhom]{tomorrow} % throws no value specified for towhom

\sayhello{today}
\end{document}
```

And here is an MWE using `pgfkeys`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{%
  /sayhello/.is family, /sayhello,
  towhom/.default=Michael,
  towhom/.store in=\sayto
}%

\newcommand*{\sayhello}[2][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/sayhello,#1}
  Say hello to \sayto\ #2.
}%
\begin{document}
%\sayhello{tomorrow} % throws undefined control sequence

\sayhello[towhom]{today}

\sayhello[towhom=Jill]{tomorrow}

\sayhello[towhom]{today}

\sayhello[towhom=Joe]{tomorrow}

\sayhello[towhom]{tomorrow}

\sayhello{today} % works perfectly
\end{document}
```

I was hoping both implementations would give identical results. They do not. `keyval` doesn't seem to like specifying a key without a value. `pgfkeys` behaves inconsistently when no options at all are given, but behaves perfectly in the cases where `keyval` didn't. Are my examples incorrectly coded? Are the inconsistencies expected behaviors? I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: "keyval doesn't seem to like specifying a key without a value" ?? the first page of `texdoc keyval`  gives the example `\define@key{dpc}{clip}[true]{...}` which defines `clip` as a key that does not have to have a value (as it defaults to true)

Comment: I missed that. I'm sorry.

Comment: Totally @DavidCarlisle's fault that you missed that for his poor documentation!

Comment: @Skillmon la la la I'm not listening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up the initial value and default value. The second is used, if you use a key without giving a value. Beside this, if you use a command to store a key value, it is good practice to define it first with `\newcommand`, as this will avoid that you overwrite existing commands.

Personally I do find `pgfkeys` more confusing, as with it the same command to define and set keys is used and understanding the behaviour of some handlers isn't always easy, see e.g [What do the pgfkeys key handlers .get and .store in do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129577/what-do-the-pgfkeys-key-handlers-get-and-store-in-do).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sh@towhom{}
\define@key{sayhello}{towhom}[Default]{\def\sh@towhom{#1}}
\setkeys{sayhello}{towhom=Initial}
\newcommand{\sayhello}[2][]{%
  \begingroup  
  \setkeys{sayhello}{#1} % Set new keys
   keyval, say hello to \sh@towhom\ #2.
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand\sayto{}
\pgfkeys{%
  /sayhello/.is family, /sayhello,
  towhom/.store in=\sayto,
  towhom/.default=Default,
  towhom = Initial,
}%

\newcommand*{\sayhellopgf}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/sayhello,#1}%
   pgfkeys, say hello to \sayto\ #2.
  \endgroup 
}%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_sayhello_towhom_tl
\keys_define:nn {sayhello}
 {
  towhom .tl_set:N = \l_sayhello_towhom_tl,
  towhom .initial:n = Initial,
  towhom .default:n = Default 
 }
 
\NewDocumentCommand\sayhelloexpl{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn{sayhello}{#1}
  l3keys,~say~hello~to~\l_sayhello_towhom_tl\c_space_tl#2
  \group_end:
 }
 
  
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\sayhello{tomorrow}

\sayhello[towhom]{today} 

\sayhello[towhom=Jill]{tomorrow}

\sayhello[towhom]{today} 

\sayhello[towhom=Joe]{tomorrow}

\sayhello[towhom]{tomorrow} 

\sayhello{today}

\sayhellopgf{tomorrow}

\sayhellopgf[towhom]{today} 

\sayhellopgf[towhom=Jill]{tomorrow}

\sayhellopgf[towhom]{today} 

\sayhellopgf[towhom=Joe]{tomorrow}

\sayhellopgf[towhom]{tomorrow} 

\sayhellopgf{today}


\sayhelloexpl{tomorrow}

\sayhelloexpl[towhom]{today} 

\sayhelloexpl[towhom=Jill]{tomorrow}

\sayhelloexpl[towhom]{today} 

\sayhelloexpl[towhom=Joe]{tomorrow}

\sayhelloexpl[towhom]{tomorrow} 

\sayhelloexpl{today}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this informative and complete answer! `keyval` seems the simplest, but I like the elegance of `l3keys`.